# SparkR and Pyspark throw Java.net.Bindexception on launch, but Spark-Shell does not?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, sparkr

I have already tried setting SPARK_LOCAL_IP to "127.0.0.1" and checking if the port is occupied. Here is the full error text:

```
Launching java with spark-submit command /usr/hdp/2.4.0.0-  

    169/spark/bin/spark-submit   "sparkr-shell" /tmp/RtmpZo44il/backend_port998540c56917
/usr/hdp/2.4.0.0-169/spark/bin/load-spark-env.sh: line 72: export: `load-spark-env.sh': not a valid identifier
16/06/13 11:28:24 ERROR RBackend: Server shutting down: failed with exception
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:125)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:485)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1089)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:430)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:415)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:903)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:198)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:348)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Error in SparkR::sparkR.init() : JVM is not ready after 10 seconds
```

Above error is when launching ./bin/sparkR. Again Spark-shell will execute normally.

Some more information. Spark-shell when launched will automatically search through ports until it has resolved one that doesn't have a bind exception. Even when I set the default SparkR backend port to an unused port it will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Another user had deleted my etc/hosts file. I reconfigured the file with localhost and it seems to run sparkR. I am still curious how spark-shell could run with the file though.